# QuickFIX/n Unsupported Message Type

Tags: quickfixn

I'm working on upgrading a VB.NET application from Quickfix.net 1.0.3 to the latest code on github (even newer than the published v1.9.0 because I need a new feature). After making the necessary changes, I'm receiving an Unsupported Message Type error from the cracker when I attempt to send in a FIX42.NewOrderSingle. I've looked through every similar issue on every forum and the issue is usually that it's not handling that particular message type, but I am handling the exact type, so I'm not sure what the problem is. I'm using the out of box specs too.

```
    Public Sub onMessage(ByVal message As FIX42.NewOrderSingle, ByVal session As QuickFix.SessionID)
        RaiseEvent Up2OMS_NewOrderSingle(message, session)
    End Sub
```

Any ideas or is there any way I can debug the issue?

Answer (score 1):

[Grant Birchmeier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650475/grant-birchmeier) on the QuickFix/n mailing list had the solution: [post on mailing list](http://lists.quickfixn.com/pipermail/quickfixn-quickfixn.com/2020q2/001124.html) I needed to capitalize the initial "o" in OnMessage.

Normally case-sensitivity wouldn't matter in VB, but in this case, there's
some internal C# code reflection that's literally looking for the exact
string "OnMessage".